# End of file error in OSClass installation in AttrDef.php

Tags: php, wordpress, osclass

I am having issues with an install of OsClass (practically wordpress for classifieds)

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/natsoft/mywebsite.com.au/oc-includes/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier/AttrDef.php on line 42
```

On line 42 of this file, is this:

```
* leading and trailing whitespace, ignoring line feeds, and replacing
```

Which is a comment - Obviously not where the issue is occurring.

I am pretty sure that this is an extra or lack of closing php tag somewhere, but I thought I'd ask the Internet before spending a whole day finding that little thing.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce the issue, do you have any plugin or theme installed? please disable them and enable them one by one. If you made any modification to any file, revert back to default. If you uploaded the files to a server, please reupload them, maybe the connection failed and some file got corrupted.

Comment: You were right. I figured it out eventually that the connection had failed / transfer faulted so majority of my files within 'oc-includes' were only half written, code cut in half so obviously no closing tags as expected.